# Requiring shipping address in PayPal adaptive payments using Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I want to set require customers to enter their shipping address when paying using PayPal adaptive payments. I've used PayPal's Rails SDK as my starting point. The `setchainedpayment` controller is working fine. From my understanding I need to set `senderOptions.requireShippingAddressSelection` to true in the `setpaymentoptions`

My question is, has anyone done this successfully using the PayPal's Rails SDK as a starting point? The SDK keeps the `setchainedpayment` and `setpaymentoptions` in separate controllers. I'm currently just calling `setchainedpayment`. In order to use `setpaymentoptions`, would i have to call `setpaymentoptions` first and then set `setpaymentoptions` to trigger `setchainedpayment`?

Seems weird to have to make two consecutive calls just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, yes. With Adaptive Payments you have two separate API calls; one for customizing the checkout, and one for calling the actually chained payment.

Disclaimer: It's been half a year since I last toyed with the Adaptive API's. :-)

Comment: Yeah, turns out they need to be separate API calls. I made the setchainedpayment call first, then just used the PayKey from that. Unfortunately, I think ``requireShippingAddressSelection`` is still only available for embedded payments. I would LOVE to just use a standard web checkout, but apparently that's not an option.

Comment: Perhaps AddressVerify or GetTransactionDetails? They're outside the Adaptive area and would thus require another API call, but at least GetTransactionDetails should return the information you're looking for (unless you're not the primary receiver, in which case you won't be allowed to call GetTransactionDetails).